# How to return null if an error for try_parse

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to simply return NULL if I get an error from TRY_PARSE. I am using TRY_PARSE to parse out a datetime from a string.

```
create table #example (
    ID int identity(1, 1)
    , extractedDateTime varchar(50)
    )

insert into #example (extractedDateTime)
values ('7/19/21    11:15')
    ,('/30/21   1100')
    ,('05/15/2021       17:00')
    ,('05/03/2021       0930')
    ,('5/26/21       09:30')
    ,('05/26/2021       0930')  
    ,('06/09/2021       12:00') 
    ,('07/06/2021       13:00')
    ,('6/15/21  12:00')
    ,('07/09/2021       07:30')
    ,('07/14/2021   13:20')
    ,('/19/2021   10:30')
    ,('7/22/21   1030')
    ,('7/21/201')
    ,('06/21/21       11:00')

select exm.ID, exm.extractedDateTime, [TRY_PARSED] = TRY_PARSE(exm.extractedDateTime as datetime2 using 'en-US')
from #example as exm

drop table #example
```

In the above example there is ID 14: '7/21/201' which will be parsed as from the year 201 (presumably it was meant to be 21 or 2021). I have gotten this to parse as datetime2, originally I was using datetime. I am inclined to still use datetime, but what I would like is to return NULL for that particular row. Instead a get a lengthy error message about a SqlDateTime overflow, because of using datetime of course.

The reason I want to go back to using datetime is this is an incorrect value, and using datetime might help filter out erroneous values like this. Also, I'd like the query to be able to return NULL anyways, whenever this little bit encounters an error so that it doesn't stop the entire query (this is part of a much larger query).

How can I return NULL for this record? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Here is the picture I get from executing the seen SELECT statement:
[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: Thanks for posting ddl! if you `try_parse` as `datetime` you should get exactly what you want, no?  `select TRY_PARSE('7/21/201' as datetime using 'en-US')` will return `null`

Comment: If I execute that select statement I get the error message "A .NET FRamework error occurred during statement execution: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow..."

Comment: I added a picture to the main post showing the error message I receive, which is not a NULL result. If you are getting NULL is it possibly due to system differences? UPDATE: Yes it is, I just tested on SQL Server 14.0... The one that gives the error message is 11.0... It'd be great to have a way to return NULL despite the error message on the 11.0 SQL Server.

Comment: Yep, looks like that got hotfixed. The answer from paneerakbari will work, you can shorten the code `iif` rather than `case`, but no, there's no way to "trap" the error on a row by row basis (that's what `try_parse` is supposed to do!)

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! I'll list paneerakbari's reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the `TRY_PARSE` is functioning as expected and documented.
That doesn't help your case, though, so I'd suggest setting an arbitrary minimum date that any date prior to that gets assigned a `NULL`.

Sample code:

```
SELECT exm.ID,
       exm.extractedDateTime,
       [TRY_PARSED] = CASE
                           WHEN TRY_PARSE(exm.extractedDateTime AS DATETIME2 USING 'en-US') < '1970-01-01'
                                THEN NULL
                           ELSE TRY_PARSE(exm.extractedDateTime AS DATETIME2 USING 'en-US')
                      END
  FROM #example AS exm;
```

Results:

| 1 | 7/19/21 | 11:15 | 2021-07-19 11:15:00.0000000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | /30/21 1100 | NULL |  |
| 3 | 05/15/2021 | 17:00 | 2021-05-15 17:00:00.0000000 |
| 4 | 05/03/2021 | 0930 | NULL |
| 5 | 5/26/21 | 09:30 | 2021-05-26 09:30:00.0000000 |
| 6 | 05/26/2021 | 0930 | NULL |
| 7 | 06/09/2021 | 12:00 | 2021-06-09 12:00:00.0000000 |
| 8 | 07/06/2021 | 13:00 | 2021-07-06 13:00:00.0000000 |
| 9 | 6/15/21 12:00 | 2021-06-15 12:00:00.0000000 |  |
| 10 | 07/09/2021 | 07:30 | 2021-07-09 07:30:00.0000000 |
| 11 | 07/14/2021 13:20 | 2021-07-14 13:20:00.0000000 |  |
| 12 | /19/2021 10:30 | NULL |  |
| 13 | 7/22/21 1030 | NULL |  |
| 14 | 7/21/201 | NULL |  |
| 15 | 06/21/21 | 11:00 | 2021-06-21 11:00:00.0000000 |

Comment: This is a good idea. I suppose there's no way to return NULL if an error message returns, however?

Comment: Per comments in main post, this is seemingly the best way to handle this for SQL Server versions that return an error instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

The advice is not to do anything since what you ask for is the default behavior of TRY_PARSE. Check the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

[image]